# How to sum based on multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, mariadb

I have got a few problems with SQL.

My tables are:

**clans**
--id

**users linked with clans**

--id

--clan_id

**clan_values linked with users**

--id

--user_id

--value

--type

I need to get different values per clan from clan_values.
One value is sum(clan_values.values) where type equals 3 as totaltime and another value is sum(clan_values.values) where type equals 1 as totalmass. I don't know how to do this. So the resultset will have full table of clan summed mass and summed time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a conditional aggregation like this:

```
SELECT u.clan_id,
       sum(case when cv.type = 3 then cv.value else 0 end) as totalTime,
       sum(case when cv.type = 1 then cv.value else 0 end) as totalMass
FROM users u
INNER JOIN clan_values cv
 ON(u.id = cv.user_id)
GROUP BY u.clan_id
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me out.